# Double/Multiple Integrals

Tags: calculus

Consider a circular lawn with a radius of 10 ft.  Assumethat a sprinkler distributes water in a radial fashion according to the formula

$$f(r) = \frac{r}{16}  -  \frac{r^2}{160}$$

(measured in cubic ft of water per hour per square ft of lawn), where $r$ is the distance in ft from the sprinkler.  Find the amount of water that is distributed in 1 hour in the following two annular regions.

$$A = \{(r,\theta): 4 \leq r \leq 5,  0 \leq θ \leq 2\pi\}$$

$$B = \{(r,\theta): 9 \leq r \leq 10,  0 \leq θ\leq 2\pi\}$$

Is the distribution of water uniform? Determine the amount ofwater the entire lawn receives in 1 hour.

Comment: I think I just have to use a double integral for f(r) over those two regions, but I don't that's right.

Answer (score 1):

For any region we want to integrate $f$ over that region to give us the amount of water, in $ft^{3}$, distributed in one hour.

So, in general we have the amount of water is
$$
\int_{D}f(r)dA
$$
where D is the region being watered.

For region A:

Amount of water is 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{4}^{5}(\frac{r}{16} - \frac{r^{2}}{160})rdrd\theta
$$

For region B:

Amount of water is 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{9}^{10}(\frac{r}{16} - \frac{r^{2}}{160})rdrd\theta
$$

and for the whole lawn:

Amount of water is 
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{10}(\frac{r}{16} - \frac{r^{2}}{160})rdrd\theta
$$

Comment: ...and the "angle integral" is separable, so you can just "pull out" $\int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta = 2 \pi$ for all three.  You get to do this because the "sprinkler function" has no dependence on direction of spraying.